# UIPickerView, static data

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uipickerview

In the Clock Application that comes with the iPhone/iPod touch, on the UIPickerView that has hours and minutes, how do we create our own picker views with the text "hours" or "mins" that is static within the UIPickerView?  I didn't see any documentation on that if that was some sort of property or anything.

Also, on that same App, they have a button that says

```
"When Timer Ends Sleep iPod >"
```

Where the text "When Timer Ends" is left justified, and the "Sleep iPod >" is right justified.  How do we do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [`-pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW1) in your UIPickerViewDelegate to set the "hours" and "minutes" titles.

For your `UITableView`, create your `UITableViewCells` with [`UITableViewCellStyleValue1`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellStyleValue1). "When Timer Ends" goes into [`textLabel`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW29), and "Sleep iPod" goes into [`detailTextLabel`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW30), I believe.